# SQL Server - Multiple images per id need to limit one image per id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query that the community helped me get to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.*
    , cast(b.Bytes as varbinary(max)) as Bytes

FROM
    (
SELECT 
    a_inner.Number
    , a_inner.Latitude
    , a_inner.Longitude
    , b_inner.RetiredOn
    , a_inner.Name
    , a_inner.Zipcode
    , b_inner.Oid

FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site a_inner
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face b_inner on b_inner.SiteId = a_inner.Oid

WHERE
    b_inner.RetiredOn LIKE '%9999%'
     AND b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR b_inner.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND b_inner.Latitude > 0.0


) AS a 
INNER JOIN "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image b on a.Oid = b.OwnerId
```

Which gives me the following results:

[image]

Each Oid has multiple images assigned to it thus it looks like I am getting duplicates. I am trying to limit my results to one image per oid so I do not get duplicates. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your `Core` table:

```
SELECT 
    a_inner.Number
    , a_inner.Latitude
    , a_inner.Longitude
    , b_inner.RetiredOn
    , a_inner.Name
    , a_inner.Zipcode
    , b_inner.OiD
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site a_inner
```

try to change:

```
LEFT JOIN Instead of Inner Join as well as below query.
```

Comment: It's not easy to test because i don't have your actual data.